# Remove matched `/api` path in Webpack proxy

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, node-http-proxy

I have a backend service running at http://localhost:9090/. All calls starting with `/api/*` should be forwarded to it, without the `/api` in front of it. So when I call `http://localhost:8080/api/my/route` it should proxy to `http://localhost:9090/my/route`.

If I use the following option:

```
proxy : [{
  path : '/api/*',
  target : 'http://localhost:9090'
}]
```

When calling `http://localhost:8080/api/my/route`, the backend service complains that it cannot find route `/api/my/route`.

The documentation suggests that I could use any options from [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy), but I can't figure out the correct options to use.

What options do I need to use to get the desired result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of webpack-dev-server version >= 1.15.0, you can use the documented [pathRewrite](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#rewriting-urls-of-proxy-request):

```
proxy: {
  '/api': {
    target: 'https://other-server.example.com',
    pathRewrite: {'^/api' : ''}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDITED** as for version <= 1.14.1
You can use the option 'rewrite'. this is a function that will be called for each request matching the pattern (eg: '/api/*'). the function must match the signature *function (req,proxyoptions) { }*

Like so :

```
proxy : [{
  path : '/api/*',
  target : 'http://localhost:9090',
  // bypass
  rewrite: function(req, options) {
    // manipulate req here 
    // in your case I think it's removing the /api part of url
  }
  // 
}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it works! Is this documented somewhere in the webpack-dev-server docs?

Comment: Great..I've found this by searching the code not found in docs. 

Warning ! After looking at the master version of webpack-dev-server's code on github [link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/master/lib/Server.js) I think the 'rewrite' function will not be supported in next versions. I'll edit the answer with a sample using bypass function instead

Comment: I've added the `rewrite` to the [docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/webpack-dev-server#rewriting-urls-of-proxy-request). As bypass already passes the response as an argument to the registered handler, I'm unsure how bypass should be able to modify the request.

Comment: you're right... I've realized that 'bypass' will not help. I think 'bypass' can be usefull  only if you want to totally bypass the proxy feature on specific pattern...

Comment: Looks like the rewrite option got replaced by the pathRewrite option - at least it got kicked out of the docs in favor of that. I'm accepting the answer by @Aprillion to help find the best answer for future problem solvers